# Working MySQL Query fails in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, phpmyadmin

I have a query, which when run from within phpMyAdmin, it works, however when integrated within a website written in Perl, it fails and throws errors.
Both are run with a connection to the same database, and from coding/formatting side when integrated into the Website, all is correct and the same as other queries.

Any help with this would be much appreciated - Thanks!

MySQL Query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_lecture_days (
timeslot_id int(50)
);
INSERT INTO tmp_lecture_days (timeslot_id)
SELECT DISTINCT tab_appointment.timeslot_id
FROM tab_appointment WHERE lecture_id = '1115';
SELECT COUNT(timeslot_id)
FROM tmp_lecture_days;
```

MySQL Query in Perl:

```
            $query
                = &statement_database(
                    "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_lecture_days (
                    timeslot_id int(50)
                    );
                    INSERT INTO tmp_lecture_days (timeslot_id)
                    SELECT DISTINCT tab_appointment.timeslot_id
                    FROM tab_appointment WHERE lecture_id = '1115';
                    SELECT COUNT(timeslot_id)
                    FROM tmp_lecture_days;");

             my ($days) = $query->fetchrow_array;
```

Error Log:

> 7.3.2011   10:14:12   error        You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
>   7.3.2011   10:14:12   error             INSERT INTO tmp_lecture_days (timeslot_id)
>   7.3.2011   10:14:12   error             SELECT DISTINCT tab_appoi' at line 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following query is equivalent to the 3 queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT timeslot_id) FROM tab_appointment
    WHERE lecture_id = '1115'
```

For more details, check the MySQL reference manual for COUNT() [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

Comment: Or that could also work - I tried combining but for some reason it went wrong. Comparing your short version to mine, just turned out I got the bracket on the wrong side of DISTINCT - Thanks a bunch XD

Answer (score 8):

If you are using DBI for running the query, you are not allowed to put more than one statement into it. Try putting `CREATE TABLE ...` into one query and `INSERT ...` into another.

Comment: Although I was thinking that could be the problem, I'm creating a temporary table there, so wouldn't closing the first query also delete the temporary table? Changing to that way would mean 4 queries to run per an entry (the fourth then being a delete table created in query one). That could cause timing issues on a long list as you are sort of quadrupling the amount you have to do.

Comment: A temporary table lives through a whole connection. Just make sure you are querying over the same connection and not make a new connection for each statement.

Comment: DBI.pm does this for your own safety. Forbidding multiple statements will often greatly limit the damage attackers can do if they find an SQL injection to exploit. The best-known use of the statement-terminating semicolon is in http://xkcd.com/327/